Linux as Build Target on Delphi FMX
I want to start developing for Linux, but Linux is not available as build destination platform. Windows, Android, macOS and iOS are within the IDE's list. The package that is missing is named "FMXLinux" as far as I found out.
I tried the following:

On setup of Delphi 12.3 I checked "Linux" as platform of course
GetIt pkg mgr does not list the "fmxlinux" package like 99% of Google results tell
I used command lines getitcmd -i=fmxlinux to do a manual installation, failed
I used command lines like getitcmd -l=linux and getitcmd -l=fmxlin* , failed
I cleared the package cache "..\CatalogRepository", no changes

On this website https://getitnow.embarcadero.com/fmxlinux/ the download link is missing for version 1.78 of the package. What can I try else? Is there a ZIP for manual installation available for registered users?

Where did you get Delphi 12.3 when newest official version that has been released by Embarcadero is Delphi 12.2?  As for getting the installation and more in depth instruction on installing FmxLinux you should probably visit FXM Linux official website

Unfortunately, FMXLinux's author, Eugene Kryukov, recently passed away:
https://blogs.embarcadero.com/eugene-kryukov-father-of-firemonkey-and-incredibly-talented-developer/
At the time of this writing, Embarcadero no longer has a valid legal agreement to include FMXLinux with Delphi 12.2. They are actively working on getting a new agreement with Eugene's estate.
In the meantime, you can try the following command:
getitcmd -i=fmxlinux-12-1.78
